# Can supremacist Purebloods (like the Malfoys) be seen wearing Muggle clothes in the books?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles, clothing

First of all I only mean books, not the movies please.

*To begin with, here is [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53815/in-the-hp-books-what-do-wizards-wear-under-their-robes) - **it doesn't reflect Draco's case though**. I do not ask what he wears under his robes, I ask if he can be seen walking around dressed like a Muggle somewhere in the books.*

So here is what I found on Draco wearing school robes:

> He pulled the robes over his head and threw them onto the floor at Madam Malkin's feet... And with that, the pair of them strode out of the shop..

So apparently he was trying his new robes on some causal closes. It would do with a jeans a t-shirt I think, but trying on robes on top of other robes doesn't make much sense. Was Draco doing his shopping on the Diagon Alley in Muggle clothing?!

And later on the train:

> To his relief, Malfoy seemed to decide that he had imagined the noise; he pulled on his robes like the others...

He pulled his robes on what? There was Pancy in the compartment and seemed like they changed all together. So were they in Muggle clothes, wearing their robes on those as Ron and Harry apparently do? Or did they have to change their common robes to the school ones?

Now I was thinking - do Pure-blood families arrive to the train station in their wizarding clothes? It seems against the Statute of Wizarding Secrecy, does it mean every year all Pure-bloods have to wear Muggle clothes to take their children to the station? Say, Lucius Malfoy?

We see at the and of *The Order of the Phoenix* that a whole bunch of adults waiting for Harry at the platform are dressed in Muggle clothing:

> There was Mad-Eye Moody, looking quite as sinister with his bowler hat pulled low over his magical eye as he would have done without it, his gnarled hands clutching a long staff, his body wrapped in a voluminous travelling cloak. Tonks stood just behind him, her bright bubble-gum-pink hair gleaming in the sunlight filtering through the dirty glass of the station ceiling, wearing heavily patched jeans and a bright purple T-shirt bearing the legend The Weird Sisters. Next to Tonks was Lupin, his face pale, his hair greying, a long and threadbare overcoat covering a shabby jumper and trousers. At the front of the group stood Mr and Mrs Weasley, dressed in their Muggle best, and Fred and George, who were both wearing brand-new jackets in some lurid green, scaly material.

Though it could be they did it only this time because they intended to talk to the Dursleys. Or not? When Harry first meets the Weasleys on the platform he never notices their clothes, only their talk about Muggles and their owl.

> Harry swung round. The speaker was a plump woman who was talking to four boys, all with flaming red hair. each of them was pushing a trunk like Harry's in front of him - and they had an owl. Heart hammering, Harry pushed his cart after them.

Does it mean all wizards obliged to dress as a Muggle when going to the platform and the Malfoys every year appear there in Muggle clothes?

Or Muggle wear is not a big deal for the new generation and Draco does occasionally wear Muggle clothing (like, in Diagon Alley) without considering it to be beneath him?

Comment: See also [Do students wear muggle clothing while not in classes at Hogwarts (like they do in the films)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144484/98028)

Comment: @Jenayah How can it be a dublicate?! I do not ask what Draco wear under his robes. And the related question does not specifically shows that all wizards wear muggle clothes underneath, does it? I ask if such snobbish pure-blood as himself can be seen walking around wearing muggle clothes anywhere in the books.

Comment: Dupe in the sense that as far as I'm concerned I'm not a big fan of having info scattered around. Now if the question can be expanded beyond Draco, something around the lines of "Do supremacist Purebloods despise muggle-like clothing" (including Death Eaters, Voldemeort etc) I reckon it'd be a better standalone question.

Comment: @Jenayah Well, I thought about all Purebloods at first, but then decided it's going to be too broad for a question. And those quotes about Draco taking his robes on and off so easily made me suspect he walk around in some trousers and shirts when out of school. Made me wonder.

Answer (score 11):

## There's no mention of Purebloods breaking the dress code for public clothes.

> The International Statute of Secrecy laid down clear guidelines on dress for witches and wizards when they are out in public.
> When mingling with Muggles, wizards and witches will adopt an entirely Muggle standard of dress, which will conform as closely as possible to the fashion of the day. Clothing must be appropriate to the climate, the geographical region and the occasion. Nothing self-altering or adjusting is to be worn in front of Muggles.
> <sub><sup>*- [Clothing - Pottemore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/clothing)*</sup></sub>

Later in the same article it mentions what Muggle haters wear.

> Day to day, however, even those who detest Muggles wear a version of Muggle clothing, which is undeniably practical compared with robes. Anti-Muggles will often attempt to demonstrate their superiority by adopting a deliberately flamboyant, out-of-date or dandyish style in public.
> <sub><sup>*- [Clothing - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/clothing)*</sup></sub>

So, we can assume that the Malfoys did wear Muggle clothes and didn't mind it because it was practical, but dressed flamboyantly or in an out of date style to show their superiority.

Comment: +1 for the Pottermore quotes, especially the second one. But in fact there are mentions of wizards (presumably purebloods) breaking the rules: first on celebrating of disappearance of Voldemort in the first book and then during the Quidditch match. It seems that the rules are not that strict.

Comment: *we can assume that the Malfoys did wear Muggle clothes ... but dressed flamboyantly or in an out of date style to show their superiority.* - makes the image of the Malfoys at the station even more bizzare :D

Comment: @ShanaTar The Ministry of Magic is not always so strict. A one-day amnesty was announced on the day that news broke of Lord Voldemort’s disappearance following Harry Potter’s survival of the Killing Curse. Such was the excitement that witches and wizards took to the streets in their traditional clothes, which they had either forgotten or adopted as a mark of celebration.

Comment: BTW thats another Pottermore quote, if you want me to edit it in i will :)

Comment: No need. Just wanted to point out that if the Ministry is not always so strict, maybe some respectful purebloods can get away with it if they are very reluctant to look ridiculous?

Comment: yeah, possibly but as seen in the quote muggle clothing is **Undeniably Practical** and since Lucius had a spot at the ministry he might not get away with wearing robes everywhere... As to the Quidditch, the only mention (i think) of breaking rules was Ludo Bagman, and i doubt Lucicus would want to be associated in any way with him :)

Comment: @padfoot Where did this idea that Lucius *worked* at the Ministry come from? I've seen a few people say that lately, but there doesn't seem to be any actual evidence for it in the books that I can recall. He just seemed to be a rich guy who met with people who worked there (in order to influence [read "bribe"] them).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist o, my bad i see... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/what-exactly-do-the-malfoys-do-for-a-living i just always assumed.....

Comment: @padfoot Off-topic, but the second quote reminded me of the time when Dumbledore went to the muggle orphanage: "...drawing many curious glances due to the flamboyantly cut suit of plum velvet..." - pretty much like an unti-muggle...

Answer (score 1):

Well, my question was more about the Malfoys, but other Death Eaters also interested me and here I found a piece of information on Voldemort himself, so I post it as an answer as - well - it is an answer in a way.

Here we see young Tom Riddle visiting Hepzibah as Borgin and Burke's worker and

> he was plainly dressed in a black suit...

I think this is an interesting mention as the whole situation is set in the wizarding world and does not suggest any contacts with Muggles. And yet, Voldemort is dressed as a proper muggle.

Answer (score 0):

Before we can talk about whether wizards want to dress like Muggles, the question is whether they even know what this means.

There is the scene at the Quiddich Cup:

> One of them was a very old wizard who was wearing a long flowery nightgown...
>
> "Just put them on, Archie, there’s a good chap, you can’t walk around like that, the Muggle on the gate’s already getting suspicious –"
>
> "I bought this in a Muggle shop," said the old wizard stubbornly. "Muggles wear them."
>
> "Muggle women wear them, Archie, not the men, they wear these," said the Ministry wizard, and he brandished the pinstriped trousers.

Even the ministry wizard, who seems to know that something is wrong, doesn't seem to know that women (or men) may wear a nightgown, but **not in public**. It would also be strange to see a woman in a nightgown in public, but the ministry wizard didn't seem to realize that.

That scene might be meant as a joke, but wizards in general are not described as up to date with fashion, and therefor not really able to blend in or behave inconspicuously.

> "You’re not the first one who’s had trouble with money," said Mr. Roberts, scrutinizing Mr. Weasley closely. "I had two try and pay me with great gold coins the size of hubcaps ten minutes ago." ...
>
> At that moment, a wizard in plus-fours appeared out of thin air next to Mr. Roberts’s front door.
>
> "Obliviate!" he said sharply, pointing his wand at Mr. Roberts. ...
>
> "Been having a lot of trouble with him. **Needs a Memory Charm ten times a day to keep him happy.**" (GoF)

This shows that many visitors are either unable to behave like Muggles, or they don't care enough despite Ministry orders, and the Ministry doesn't really try to enforce it, it's easier to modify a Muggle's memory, and it's not like anybody cares about the effect of ten obliviations a day. And it' not like the obliviations are without side effects. While Mr Weasley said he will be all right eventually, I doubt anybody bothered to verify that.

> Mr Roberts had a strange, dazed look about him, and he waved them off with a vague ‘Merry Christmas'.
>
> "He’ll be all right," said Mr Weasley quietly, as they marched off onto the moor. "Sometimes, when a person’s memory’s modified, it makes them a bit disorientated for a while ... and that was a big thing they had to make him forget."

Even Arthur Weasley, who is supposed to be interested in Muggles, doesn't know about currency, as seen earlier, or electricity.

> "Really? [**Ecklectic**](https://www.pottermore.com/quote/ekecltricity), you say? With a plug? Gracious, I must see that..."

We also don't see much need for wizards to blend in with Muggles, so why should they try, and if they try, why restrict their effort just to clothes, as their behavior would reveal them anyway?